# What is 'Churchillian knock-off'?

Tags: design-patterns, xunit

I've read xUnit Test Patterns.
http://martinfowler.com/books.html
There is 'Churchillian knock-off' expression in Martin Fowler's writes like this...

If you go to junit.org, you'll see a quote from me: "never in the field of software development have so many owed so much to so few lines of code". JUnit has been criticized as a minor thing, something any reasonable programmer could produce in a weekend. This is true, but utterly misses the point. The reason JUnit is important, and deserves the Churchillian knock-off, is that the presence of this tiny tool has been essential to a fundamental shift for many programmers. A shift where testing has moved to a front and central part of programming. People have advocated it before, but JUnit made it happen more than anything else.

I have failed to search about 'Churchillian knock-off'.
Could you help me know what it means?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq -- except, that he's probably right.  I'd say that virtually all of TDD could probably be attributed to the presence of jUnit.  I'd say that's a huge paradigm shift for a few lines of code.

Comment: “Those who do not learn from history are doomed to repeat it”

Comment: @Pascal - I'm told that they called it "creat" to make up for the fact that "lseek" had that extra "l". :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"never in the field of software development have so many owed so much to so few lines of code" is stolen from Winston S. Churchill's speech referring to the Battle of Britain. Churchill said:

"Never in the field of human conflict, has so much been owed by so many to so few" (quoting from memory).

Comment: Exactly- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_was_so_much_owed_by_so_many_to_so_few

Comment: Referring to the role of the RAF in the Battle of Britain. ;)

Comment: "Never in the field of human combat have so many owed so much to so few ... "

Answer (score 3):

He's referring to the "never in the field" quote - Churchill said something very similar about the Battle of Britain.